# c# Is it possible to subtract a day in the datetime format

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetime-format

I have the following simple example:

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");
```

I can't change the `DateTime.Now`, but I can change datetime format `yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss`. Following this example the result must be today's date, but I need to get yesterday's date with the same parameters except day (year, month, hours, minutes and seconds). E.g. 2015-08-23 12.09.59 must be 2015-08-22 12.09.59. So is it possible to use some "-" operator or something else inside the datetime format to achieve the result?

Comment: `I can't change the DateTime.Now,` but why?

Comment: Because I'm working with the library, and I can set to it only datetime pattern

Comment: So just wrap Arghya C's answer in a DateTime parse? (Definitely not preferred)

Comment: Why those downvotes? For me, this question was helpful. I wondered if this would be possible, searched in MSDN, did not find a clear "no", searched the web, came here and finally found the answer here. Perfect. I am really thankful for this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> E.g. 2015-08-23 12.09.59 must be 2015-08-22 12.09.59. So is it
>   possible to use some "-" operator or something else inside the
>   datetime format to achieve the result?

No, it's not possible inside the DateTime format. you can not change any thing. Because it is only for define format of the Date to display in string format. Any addition or subtraction can only be done before converting it to string format as suggested by "Arghya C".

Can you explain your limitation so we can solve your problem.

Comment: I'm working with the library, and I can set to it only datetime pattern, so thanks for your reply

Answer (score 7):

If you want yesterday's date, you can do this

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");
```

`DateTime.AddDays()` lets you add number of days, positive for future date, negative for past date.

Comment: why? Why can't you just type that in?

Comment: Because I'm working with the library, and I can set to it only datetime pattern

Comment: @Mia Do you have access to the library's code? If so, can't you amend or add to it for your requirement?

Comment: @Mia If, you can get a string value of DateTime from your library by specifying the format, you see Oliver's answer for the workaround. If the method is void refer Kishan's answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you can only influence the date time pattern, than use the [roundtrip format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) and parse the returning string back to a date time, add the calculation and format it into the desired format:

```
var dateTimeString = badLibrary.GetDateTime("o");
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
var newDateTime = dateTime.AddDays(-1);

return newDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss");
```

Comment: If the library returns a string representation of the date based on the specified format, this should work for op. If the method is void, there's no solution!